# Spring configuration in Java - Create and use 2 beans of same class NOT using Autowired

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, javabeans

I know the question of how to create and use two Spring beans of the same type has been answered before, and I've read a little bit about @Qualifier, and @Resource, but all the answers I've seen are in the context of autowiring.  In my case the place I'm trying to use the bean is in another part of the config file(s), so I'm not sure which parts of the solution apply.  I've also got a case were we're doing config in multiple ways (xml config files, and a java file with the @Configuration annotation.    Here's what the code looks like

```
import com.this.that.AuthProvider;
@Configuration
...
    @Bean
    public AuthProvider buildAuthProvider() {
        return new AuthProvider(someotherbean);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyConnectionManager buildMyConnectionManager(AuthProvider authProvider) {
        return new MyConnectionManager(authProvider);
    }
    ...
```

another spring config xml file imported into application-config.xml

```
  <bean id="MyAuthProvider" class="com.this.that.AuthProvider">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" ref="somedifferentbean" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="MyClient" class="com.that.this.MyClient">
    <constructor-arg type="com.this.that.AuthProvider"
      ref="MyAuthProvider" />
  </bean>
```

When I do this there's an error trying to create MyConnectionManager in the Java configuration file.  The error is on the the constructor arg with the following info )
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException .. (excpected single bean but found 2: MyAuthProvider, buildMyConnectionManager())

I also see another bean in here that refers to the AuthProvider class, but instead of just specifying it as an argument into the bean constructor it uses a parameterless constructor and creates a new AuthProvider using the 'buildAuthProvider()' method.  I dont' see any complaint about that or the bean created in the xml file, but I'm not sure if this error is just masking the others.

Can someone help me figure out how to have these two separate beans?  They get created with a different value passed to their constructor, so I can't re-use the same bean in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with multiple beans of the same type you need to qualify them with names.  In XML configurations, this comes quite naturally with the *name=""* attribute.  In Java based configurations you need to add the name to the annotation, *@Bean(name = "")*.

Next, you can reference the bean from anywhere within the Spring Context.  In Java you would use the *@Qualifier* annotation, which works when declaring Java beans or when using the *@Autowired* annotation for injection into Spring managed classes.

Java configuration example:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    /**
     * Define bean-one, which can be referenced in Java config or XML config.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "bean-one")
    public String whoAmI(){
        return "bean 1.";
    }

    /**
     * Create a bean with the who am I from the XMl config.
     * @param whoAmI
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "xml-message")
    public String xmlMessage(@Qualifier("bean-two") String whoAmI){
        return "I am " + whoAmI;  // I am bean 2
    }

    /**
     * Define the bean with the who am I from the Java config
     * @param whoAmI
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name="java-message")
    public String javaMessage(@Qualifier("bean-one") String whoAmI){
        return "I am " + whoAmI; // I am bean 1
    }
}
```

Do note the location of the *@Qualifier* annotation, if not in front of the method argument it will not work.

XML Configuration example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">


    <!-- Find my other context -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="test.spring"/>

    <!-- Declare bean to to be injected into the any of the message objects. -->
    <bean class="java.lang.String" name="bean-two">
        <constructor-arg value="bean two"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Notice that we reference Java config "Bean-One" by using the name assigned -->
    <bean class="java.lang.String" name="xml-message-two">
        <constructor-arg ref="bean-one"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Notice that we reference Java config "Bean-Two" by using the name assigned -->
    <bean class="java.lang.String" name="java-message-two">
        <constructor-arg ref="bean-two"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use qualifier to distinguish the two beans.

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("myJDBCTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("myJDBCTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```